# Creates a service that keeps alive even activity finishes

Tags: android, service

I am new in Android and i don't know how do this.
I need do a service in Android that keeps alive even Activity finishes. I do this:

Activity:

```
package com.example.pruebaservice;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button telo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        telo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        telo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startService(new Intent(this, PruebaService.class));
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package com.example.pruebaservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PruebaService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio creado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("SERVICEBOOT", "Servicio creado");
        prueba();
    }

    private void prueba() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(;;){
        Log.i("telo","motoor");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("SERVICEBOOT", "Servicio destruido");
    }
}
```

But when activity is on pause or destroy service crashes. How can i do this?

thanks

Comment: asked so many times ... google for startForeground

Answer (score 0):

service never kill until you are not going to uninstall the application. or kill the service programmatically.
its all upon your logic that how particular task you want to do continuous because when service is started its go through out the code once.
you have to maintain the timer for regular checking. please improve the logic of the code. that check your functionality in the background time to time